# How to get bash code to work on all files in folders and subfolders?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a code that using `ffmpeg` to conver `*.avi` to `*.mp4` on all files in the folder. I want it to run on all folders and sub folders; and to save the result in this subfolder.

I tried already with find but no success

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.avi; 
do
    ffmpeg -i /location/"$i" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
       -strict -2 -n /location/"$(basename  "$i" .avi)".mp4
done
```

Comment: And what's the error with the code above?

Comment: `/location/"$(basename ...)"` looks suspicious. Do you really have a folder called `location` in the root of the filesystem?

Comment: If you'd show what you _tried already with find but no success_, we could tell how to fix it.

Comment: location is X... error is that while code missing here. look down on Maxim's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to find matching files in all sub-directories:

```
find <top-dir> -iname "*.avi" | while read filename; do ffmpeg -i "$filename" ... "${filename%avi}mp4"; done
```

Replace `...` with your `ffmpeg` options.

You can also use GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) utility to parallelize processing of found files over multiple CPUs:

```
find <top-dir> -iname "*.avi" | parallel -i -- ffmpeg -i "{}" ... "{.}.mp4"
```